# Facebook App. with GWT

Tags: gwt, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am writing a Facebook Application using the Google Web Toolkit. My methodology to authenticate users is using the graph-api to get the access token with Open authentication  as told in this article:

[restfb: Writing a facebook application with java (using the new graph api)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248484/restfb-writing-a-facebook-application-with-java-using-the-new-graph-api)

But in the very first step. Facebook doesn't allow to redirect to a page(even if it's facebook itself) from the canvas. So it creates a link. I guess there's a php solution for this in this article:

[How to authorize Facebook app using redirect in canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380876/how-to-authorize-facebook-app-using-redirect-in-canvas)

How can we apply this solution(or any other solution) to GWT directly in Java?

Answer (score 2):

Best option is to use JAVAScript and wrap it with JSNI, otherwise do it from the backend.
There's an existing library that you can use: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-facebook/